# Altium PCB side dimension bar

Tags: pcb, altium

[image]

This dimension box is moving with my mouse. How can I close this thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your mouse so that the box sits back in the top left of your display (or wherever you want it to sit permanently) and press Shift G to dock it.